# Can't pickle the sqlAlchemy engine in the class

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing, pickle

I want to use multiprocessing module with sqlAlchemy in my custom class. 
Here is the code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://a:b@localhost:3306/', server_side_cursors=True, pool_size=20)


class Client(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://a:b@localhost:3306/', server_side_cursors=True, pool_size=20)
        self.pool = Pool(6)

    def run_in_process(self, x): 
        conn = self.engine.connect()
        print(conn)

    def run(self):
        x = 'x' 
        res = self.pool.apply_async(self.run_in_process, (x,))
        res.get()

    def __getstate__(self):
        self_dict = self.__dict__.copy()
        del self_dict['pool']
        return self_dict

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.__dict__.update(state)


pool = Pool(6)
client = Client()
client.run()
```

It showed errors:

```
  File "test_pickle.py", line 32, in <module>
    client.run()
  File "test_pickle.py", line 19, in run
    res.get()
  File "/home/airflow/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/home/airflow/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 431, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/home/airflow/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/home/airflow/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: can't pickle _thread._local objects
```

I know the multiprocessing sometimes is troublesome because of pickle and I know this problem is due to the **self.engine**, as it can't be pickled. But I have to use `engine` this variable in the class.

So, how can I make the engine pickable in my example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing the same problem :)

Comment: any updates on the issue?

Comment: Hi, I'm also having the same problem. Did you find a solution?